# in file there is set of start and end point i need to extract the data between those two points and again read another set of points

Tags: python

```
*******************************************
START point 1
data 1 
data 2
data 3
data 4
END point 1

*******************************************
START point 2
data 1 
data 2
data 3
data 4
END point 2
*******************************************
*******************************************
START point 3
data 1 
data 2
data 3
data 4
END point  3
*******************************************
*******************************************
START point 4 
data 1 
data 2
data 3
data 4
END point 4
*******************************************
```

1.The START Point and END point is all the same name i had given numbers only to provide the differnet set of data in the file.

2. I need to read the 1st set of start and end point do some code transaction and again read 2nd set of start and end point and do some code transaction. and continue doinf untill complete all the start and end point in the file.

Thank you in advance

Code:

```
import re
def read_file():

    file_out = open("file_path.txt", "rb")

    start_rx = re.compile('.SUBCKT')
    end_rx = re.compile('.ENDS')

    start = False
    output = []

    with file_out as data_file:
        for line in data_file.readlines():
            if re.match(start_rx, line):
                start = True
            elif re.match(end_rx, line):
                start = False
            if start :
                output.append(line)
        print(output)
    #print(output[1])

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    read_file()
```

Output :

```
  ['.SUBCKT t9_invx0p5_znrw2 Z VDD VNW VPW VSS A\n', 'MP1 Z A VDD VNW pfet l=1.4e-08 nf=1 nfin=2 fpitch=4.8e-08 cpp=8.4e-08 ngcon=1 p_la=2e-09 plorient=0\n', 'MN1 Z A VSS VPW nfet l=1.4e-08 nf=1 nfin=2 fpitch=4.8e-08 cpp=8.4e-08 ngcon=1 p_la=2e-09 plorient=0\n', '.SUBCKT t9_invx0p75_znrw2 Z VDD VNW VPW VSS A\n', 'MP1 Z A VDD VNW pfet l=1.4e-08 nf=1 nfin=3 fpitch=4.8e-08 cpp=8.4e-08 ngcon=1 p_la=2e-09 plorient=0\n', 'MN1 Z A VSS VPW nfet l=1.4e-08 nf=1 nfin=3 fpitch=4.8e-08 cpp=8.4e-08 ngcon=1 p_la=2e-09 plorient=0\n']
```

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget [how to format your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read data between START and END point and save them in list to do any additional work:

```
the_list = []
dataList = []
with open('putt.txt', "r") as f:
    isLine = False
    for line in f:
        if "END point" in line:
            print(the_list)
            # do whatever you want with these lines
            dataList.append(the_list)
            the_list = []
            isLine = False
        if "START point" in line:
            isLine = True
        if "START point" not in line and isLine:
            if(len(line)>0):
                the_list.append(line)
```

output:

```
['data 1 \n', 'data 2\n', 'data 3\n', 'data 4\n']
['data 1 \n', 'data 2\n', 'data 3\n', 'data 4\n']
['data 1 \n', 'data 2\n', 'data 3\n', 'data 4\n']
['data 1 \n', 'data 2\n', 'data 3\n', 'data 4\n']

print(dataList[0])
```

output:

```
['data 1 \n', 'data 2\n', 'data 3\n', 'data 4\n']
```

Comment: HI Thank you For the answer i am able to get  the output but 1 problem is if i print(the_list[0]) the answer is only data 1 data 1 data 1 data 1

Comment: i need to have it has print(the_list[0]) the answer would be

Comment: ['data 1 \n', 'data 2\n', 'data 3\n', 'data 4\n']